# Python dataframe - Convert object dataframe column to a mm/dd format

Tags: python, pandas

I have few dataframe columns, I wanted to convert an object column into an mm/dd format. Currently my column contains the below values:

```
date_column
31-Dec
-
09-Aug
sometext
28-Feb
```

I need the desired output in the below format:

```
desired_output
12/31
-
08/09
sometext
02/28
```

I tried the below 2 lines of code, but I get the following error: `ValueError: time data '31-Dec' does not match format '%MM%dd' (match)`

```
df['value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'], format="%MM%dd")
df['value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'], format="%mm%dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a record as a string for the 1 January. First, you need to convert it into a datetime object:

```
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('1-Jan', '%d-%b')
```

Next, to get the desired output:

```
y = datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%m/%d')
```

This produces:

```
print(y)
01/01
```

You need to apply the above procedure to your columns.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried  in my dataframe column, i get the below error:                                                                          df['value'] = datetime.strptime(df['value'], '%d-%b')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: You can use a list comprehension: `df['value'] = [datetime.strptime(value, '%d-%b') for value in df['value']]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regex:

```
mask = df.date_column.str.match("\d\d-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)")

new = df.date_column[mask].add('-00').pipe(pd.to_datetime).dt.strftime("%m/%d")

df.loc[mask, 'date_column'] = new
```

**Output**

```
df
  date_column
0       12/31
1           -
2       08/09
3    sometext
4       02/28
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the series of string to pandas datetime and then get the formatted string using [series.dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
df['value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'], format = "%d-%b").dt.strftime("%m/%d")
```